# How commits are kept in order

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Quick question on Mercurial.  Suppose my colleague and I both have an up to date copy of trunk.  We both make changes, then we both push/pull the changes from each other.

I am guessing Mercurial keeps the changes in order based on the date of the commit (since there is no incrementing revision, just a GUID).  So what happens if my computer's date is one day behind and I commit half a day after my colleague.  Would my change show up half a day before my colleague's?

Comment: This is an interesting question! Are HG hashes timestamp based? I always assumed they were, but thinking about it, why should they be?

Comment: @Neil: There is no central authoritative server (like in CVS/SVN) to keep commits in order.  I can't think of anything other than a timestamp to keep things in order when commits are decentralized.  There could be some checks when commits are pushed/pulled, but that wouldn't know if the date was wrong when committed, then fixed before the push/pull.  I suppose I could test this to see if it's a problem, but I would like more insight into how that is handled internally, whether it is a problem or not.

Comment: I've got a long winded answer below, but just to tack on you don't need to muck with your computer's date.  You can set the date on the commit using the `--date` option.  They're purely decorative.

Comment: http://hginit.com http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, your changesets are timestamped (internally stored as seconds-since-the-UNIX-epoch and a timezone offset), and when displaying changeset, they are ordered by timestamp and your changesets will be displayed in the incorrect place as their timestamps are be incorrect. See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ChangeSet

This is not really that much of a problem though; timestamps have no bearing on how your changes are merged with those of your colleague. Only the changeset IDs matter here and when merging a common ancestor is used. It'll follow the graph of your changesets down looking for a changeset ID that your colleague also has and then merges your and his changes from the on forward. See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Merge

So, merges are not affected, only the display of changesets, where your changesets will be sorted into the wrong location. It'll confuse  you and your colleague, but your changes themselves are safe.

Comment: Ok, but if we both rename the same variable, the "last" (possibly incorrect) changeset wins?  What if my colleague renamed a variable in `abc.cs` to `foo`.  Half a day later I rename the same variable to `bar` and add `def.cs` which references `bar`.  We push/pull.  We now have `abc.cs` with `foo` (his change appears last), but `def.cs` has `bar`.  The code doesn't compile.

Comment: This is a merge conflict and you'll have to resolve this. Neither change wins. See http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Conflict

Comment: True, since the same text changed--let's try another scenario.  He adds `abc.cs` with `foo` and commits.  I pull his changes, create `def.cs` which references `foo` and commit half a day later.  How is my commit stored locally, since I committed it "half a day before" his change?  Can I even commit with an earlier date than the last commit in my repository?  Will it drop the delta from his commit to the previous (let's call it initial) commit, stick mine in between, then generate a delta between initial->mine and mine->his?

Comment: ...If it sticks my commit before his, I am referencing a non-existent variable.  If it adds my commit at the end, then it can't be using my computer's timestamp...?

Comment: Again, the dates are not used to compare changesets, only to display changeset lists in an ordered manner. So yes, you can commit, no it will not be dropped. Your commits are relative (connected as a graph) to your own working directory root (changeset) and are compared as a graph with your colleague, completely ignoring timestamps. It's all explained in detail in the articles I linked to. To re-iterate, your changes and his changes are separate lines in the graph, so you never insert 'in between' his changesets. Your graphs are merged with a new commit, joining the lines.

Comment: I read the links you sent, but I think I know what I was missing earlier.  Even if we are both working on trunk, we are treated as separate non-named branches that have to be merged?  That seems implied in the merge article: "A merge **combines two separate changesets** in a repository into a merge changeset that describes how they combine. Merging is the process of **joining points on two branches** into one."  ...thus each changeset is its own branch?

Comment: No, each user (effectively) has their own branch (consisting of their changesets). Quoted from the linked article on merging: *"Every working directory is potentially a branch and every user effectively works in their own branch."*

Comment: Maybe I worded it wrong, but aren't these essentially the same?  `your changes and his changes are separate lines in the graph` == `each user (effectively) has their own branch` == `we are treated as separate non-named branches`.  I think the last bit I had wrong is that each changeset was its own branch--incorrect since a branch can have multiple changesets.  I do believe I have it down now.

Answer (score 7):

@Martijn has your correct answer, but it doesn't seem to be clicking.  If this makes anything clear pick his:

- The commit times on Mercurial changesets have absolutely nothing to do with how they're merged, interleaved, or combined

Mercurial, and other DVCs, do all history tracking based entirely on the DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph), which means:

- the **only** piece of metadata that matters is the parent or parents of a changeset

Before you commit you can see what the parent of your changeset is going to be by typing `hg parents` and once you commit you can see it in the `hg log`.

In your examples if you've pulled your colleague's changesets and updated your working directory to reflect them (`hg pull ; hg update`) then his or her changeset will be the parent of your changeset.  If you haven't pulled/updated to reflect his or her changeset then both of your changesets will have the same parent -- they'll be siblings -- when when they're merged neither will take precedence over the other in any way.

The ordering when you do a `hg log` is determined by the order in which the changeset arrived in **your** local repository, and can differ from repo to repo depending on where they've pulled from first -- that's why you can't use the integer numbers shown next to changesets for cross-repo operations -- only the hash is global.

In short the date is **never** consulted in normal operations and is **purely metadata** with no more relevance than the author or commit description.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.  The main things I needed: timestamps are only used for display, each user effectively has their own branch (due to having the same parent & being siblings), the log order can vary between computers depending on when the changesets were pulled...  So if you had a "central" repository (e.g. bitbucket), its order would be determined by when changesets are pushed.  If every developer cleared their local repositories and pulled from bitbucket, they all would have the same log order up to that point in time.  Makes sense...

Comment: Yup, sounds like you got everything.  Good deal.

Answer (score 4):

The order of changesets is not affected by the timestamp in the changesets. The order is determined solely by the order in which the changesets were created in your local repository.

Mercurial has an append-only architecture so when you pull from another repository, the changesets you pull in are placed after your own changesets, regardless of the timestamps in the new changesets.

The revision numbers (the local integer counter) is just a counter: each new changeset gets the next available revision number. The simple range operator in Mercurial works directly on revisions numbers, and so `X:Y` means "give me changesets with revision numbers from X to Y (inclusive)". This is not so useful when the revision numbers are based only on the order in which changesets were created or pulled into a repository.

Use `X::Y` instead, that gives you changesets that are descendants of X and ancestors of Y, i.e., it follows the branches in the history.

Comment: I knew the revision numbers didn't mean much.  Thanks for confirming about the order, which supports what @Ry4an said (The ordering when you do a hg log is determined by the order in which the changeset arrived in your local repository) and contradicts what @Martijn said (when displaying changeset, they are ordered by timestamp).